# Change the image of a specific cell inside a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a 5x5 grid of cells in a UICollectionView, each with an image set like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"circleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    imageArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    for (int i=1; i<=12; i++) {
        UIImage *imageToAdd = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
        [imageArray addObject:imageToAdd];
    }

    self.cellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[self getCircleSize]];
    int i = arc4random() % 12;
    [self.cellImageView setImage:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    [cell addSubview:self.cellImageView];
    cell.tag = i;
    return cell;
}
```

Each image is a circle of a random color - 1.png to 12.png.
I am detecting taps on a specific cell, and then getting it's color and position in the collection view:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

self.firstCircleSection = indexPath.section;
self.firstCircleRow = indexPath.row;
self.firstCircleIndex = (indexPath.section * 5) + (indexPath.row + 1);

self.firstCircleNum = (int)cell.tag;
//I have a dictionary with colors and keys, e.g 1 Yellow, 2 Blue, 3 Red. This line gets the color:
NSString *dotColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Colour: %@", [self.colorDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", self.firstCircleNum]]];
```

Then for the second circle tap of another circle, I am calculating what the new color of each circle will be (a color in the middle of the two selected colors):

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];

self.secondCircleSection = indexPath.section;    
self.secondCircleRow = indexPath.row;    
self.secondCircleIndex = (indexPath.section * 5) + (indexPath.row + 1);
self.secondCircleNum = (int)cell.tag;

NSString *circleColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Colour: %@", [self.colorDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", self.secondCircleNum]]];

NSInteger i = (self.firstCircleNum + self.secondCircleNum)/2;
NSString *dotColor = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Colour: %@", [self.colorDict objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", i]]];

// Labels on the view for showing what the colors mix like
colorLabel2.text = circleColor;
positionLabel2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Position: %ld", self.secondCircleIndex];
mixedColorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"New %@", dotColor];

NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.firstCircleRow inSection:self.firstCircleSection];
NSInteger theFirstCircleIndex = (indexPath2.section * 5) + (indexPath2.row + 1);
NSIndexPath *indexPath3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.secondCircleRow inSection:self.secondCircleSection];
NSInteger theSecondCircleIndex = (indexPath3.section * 5) + (indexPath3.row + 1);

// Get a reference to the two cells
UICollectionViewCell *firstCircle = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"circleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath2];
UICollectionViewCell *secondCircle = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"circleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath3];
```

My question is, once I have done all this, how can I change the image of those two cells - firstCircle and secondCircle? I have a property on the custom CollectionViewCell, cellImage, but am unable to access it with: firstCircle.cellImage. I want to change the image on both cells.

Comment: Have you used the debugger to step through your last code sample? After you deque the cells, what type are they actually? You are saying that the references are normal collection view cells though they are likely your custom cell class. In which case, if you cast them properly xcode will be able to help you out. Lastly, you are declaring the same variable twice at the very end of your code sample.

Comment: That was a copy-paste mistake from the first variable declaration. I'm just wanting to know how to change the image on the cell at indexPath2 and indexPath3. If I have a UIImageView on the custom cell, how can I a) Get a reference to the cell and b) change the image of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, you are creating a new `UIImageView`, setting its image from your array, and adding it as a subview of the cell.  This is different from the `cellImage` property of the cell.  To fix this:

**Either:**
If you have configured your custom `CollectionViewCell` in a storyboard (i.e. added an image view to the prototype cell, and hooked it up to the CollectionViewCell's `cellImage` outlet), then you needn't add the extra `UIImageView` you can just use:

```
cell.cellImage.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
```

**Or:**
If it's not configured in a storyboard (or the CollectionViewCell initialiser), then keep your existing code, but set cell.cellImage to point to the imageView you created:

```
cell.cellImage = self.cellImageView;
```

**Next:**
In your other code (which I assume is in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`?), the following line tells the compiler that cells are of the base `UICollectionViewCell` class:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

But you want the compiler to know that these cells are actually your custom CollectionViewCell class.  So amend the line to:

```
CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

(and similarly elsewhere).  That done, the compiler should then let you use the `cellImage` property without problem.

Now, to get a reference to the cells for `indexPath2` and `indexPath3`, don't use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method, use `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` (just as you do in the first line):

```
CollectionViewCell *firstCircle = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath2];
CollectionViewCell *secondCircle = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath3];
```

You can then manipulate their images with `firstCircle.cellImage.image` etc.

Also, there is some redundancy in your code: with these lines:

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

you are getting the cell for a given indexPath, and then getting the indexPath for that cell - it will be the same.  So you can delete the second of these lines.  Also, in the code which handles `secondCircle`, `indexPath3` is the same as `indexPath`, and `secondCircle` will actually be the `cell` that you set at the start of the code.  So just use:

```
CollectionViewCell *secondCircle = cell;
```

Finally, your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` loads the imageArray every time it is called - which is unnecessary.  I would use a different method to load these images - perhaps the `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: When I replace `UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];` with `CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];`, I get a warning: Incompatible pointer types initializing 'CollectionViewCell *' with an expression of type 'UICollectionViewCell *'.

Comment: Sorry, you need to cast it with (CollectionViewCell *) - I will amend my answer.